# Mockito spy returns different result than actual method call

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, vtd-xml

I have the following code:

```
public Object parse(){
      ....
      VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
      boolean parsed = vg.parseFile(myFile.getAbsolutePath(), false);
}
```

I am writing a unit test for this method. When I run the method without mocking `VTDGen` the `parseFile` method returns `true`. However, when I mock it with a spy, it returns `false`.

My test is as follows:

```
@Before
public void setup(){
     VTDGen vtgGen = new VTDGen();
     VTDGen vtgGenSpy = PowerMockito.spy(vtdGen);
     PowerMockito.whenNew(VTDGen.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(vtdGenSpy);

}


@Test
public void myTest(){
    // when I run the test parseFile returns false
    // if I remove the mocking in the setup, parseFile returns true
}
```

I was under the impression that Mockito's spy objects should not change the behavior of wrapped objects, so why am I getting false instead of true?

Comment: I need more help from you, either in your myTest() method or in your parse() method or maybe VTDGen.parseFile(). You are creating a spy, but I don't see the verification code.  Where does myFile come from? I probably don't need ALL of that information, but more than what you've given so far.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Weekend stuff. `myTest` calls `parse` and `myFile` is passed in. The point is that if I comment out `PowerMockito.whenNew`, `vg.parseFile` returns `true` but with the `whenNew` in place (so the spy is used) `vg.parseFile` returns `false`. I thought the spy should just wrap a call to the actual instance, so why is the returned value different?

Comment: So you're not doing any actual 'spying' on your spy right now? How do you know what `vg.parseFile` is returning?

Comment: Debugger. The return from `parse` was not what I was trying to test but is preventing me from getting to the code I am testing. I pulled out everything else that might be affecting the test and got down to the spy causing the problem.

Comment: Does `vtdGenSpy.parseFile(myFile.getAbsolutePath(), false)` (without PowerMockito) return `false` too?

Comment: No. Without the spy it returns true. With the spy it returns false.

Comment: Sorry, did you really ask about calling `parseFile` on the `spy` without `PowerMockito` or ask about the actual code under test without the spy.

Comment: @JohnB If you change the `whenNew ... thenReturn` call to return `vtgGen` does the same thing occur?

Comment: @Bringer128 with `thenReturn(vtgGen)` `parse` returns `true` as expected

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is because you are returning `vtdGenMock` not `vtgGenSpy` in

`PowerMockito.whenNew(VTDGen.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(vtdGenMock);`

Answer (score 1):

When spying on Powermocked classes you should use the `PowerMockito.spy(...)` method:

```
VTDGen vtgGenSpy = PowerMockito.spy(vtdGen);
```

Also ensure your version combinations of Mockito/Powermock are compatible. I'm using Mockito 1.8.5 and Powermock 1.4.10.

The following tests (TestNG) pass for me:

```
@PrepareForTest({VTDGen.class, Uo.class})
public class UoTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

    private VTDGen vtdGen;
    private VTDGen vtdGenSpy;
    private Uo unitUnderTest;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        vtdGen = new VTDGen();
        vtdGenSpy = PowerMockito.spy(vtdGen);
        unitUnderTest = new Uo();
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithSpy() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(VTDGen.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(vtdGenSpy);

        boolean result = unitUnderTest.parse();

        assertTrue(result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithoutSpy() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(VTDGen.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(vtdGen);

        boolean result = unitUnderTest.parse();

        assertTrue(result);
    }
}
```

For unit under test:

```
public class Uo {
    public boolean parse() {
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        return vg.parseFile("test.xml", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it with `PowerMockito.spy` to no avail. How can I tell if Powermock / Mockito are compatible? I have using Mockito 1.8.5 and Powermock 1.4.9 (I don't have access to PowerMock 1.4.10).

Comment: Looks like as of PowerMock 1.3.9, it supported Mockito 1.8.5

Answer (score 1):

This was in orien's reply although sort of indirectly: Did you include @PrepareForTest(ClassCallingNewVTDGen.class)?

It's the class calling

```
new VTDGen()
```

that has to be prepared for test. In orien's answer, it is Uo.class

[Source](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#How_to_mock_construction_of_new_objects)

Comment: Yes I did. I did confirm that the class under test received the spy.